# TimeBased and SizeBased policies together for RollingFile in Log4j 2

Tags: java, log4j2, rollingfileappender

My requirement(values customized for test purpose):

1. Log files should be of max size 1KB, beyond which new log file should be generated keeping the previous file untouched. I am not concerned about the max number of files generated by this. It shall have no upper limit.
2. Every minute, the previous minute's log files should be converted to .zip.
   So, if time is 14:00:01, suppose 100 log files got generated for this due to 1 KB restriction. Now at 14:00:02, previous second's 100 log files should get converted to 100 .zip files, and by end of 14:00:02, I should have  another lot of 100 log files.

So, at the start of 14:00:03, i should have 100 .log files for 14:00:02 and 100 .zip files for 14:00:01.

I have tried various combinations of param values and policies but have not been able to achieve this. When I am using both policies, I am getting .zip files as soon as 1KB limit is exceeded. Below is my config. Please let me know where I am going wrong:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/utility.log" filePattern="logs/utility-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}-%i.zip" >
  <PatternLayout>
    <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <Policies>
   <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
<SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB" />
</Policies>
</RollingFile>
```

If am modifying it to below, I am not getting any zip files:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/utility.log" filePattern="logs/utility-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}-%i.log" >
  <PatternLayout>
    <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <Policies>
   <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy>
    <param name="FileNamePattern" value="logs/utility-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}-%i.zip" />
   </TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy> 
<SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 KB" />
</Policies>
</RollingFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Triggering policies are just that - methods the appender should use to figure out when a file rollover should occur. Compression happens automatically on each rollover if the file pattern ends with a "normal" compressed file extension. To change that behavior you would have to create a custom action to find all the files created in the prior minute and compress them.

Actions are specified like

```
<RollingFile ...>
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy>`
    <Delete basePath="${baseDir}" maxDepth="2">
      <IfFileName glob="*/app-*.log.gz" />
      <IfLastModified age="60d" />
    </Delete>
  </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
</RollingFile>
```

Comment: By custom action, do you mean schedule a job?

Comment: The RollingFileAppender uses "Action" plujgins to perform certain operations like renaming files, compressing them, and deleting them. You can write your own custom Action plugin and add it to the configuration as I have shown above.

Comment: Ok, will try to implement this. Thanks much!!